# Вставка содержимого с страницы плагина в другую страницу

Tags: php, wordpress, функции, шаблоны

Есть шаблон на Вордпрессе с недвижимостью. Хочу вывести на отдельную страницу 1 объект. Но в документации никакой информации нет и гугле ноль информации. Облазил шаблон и нашел страницу, которая отвечает за вывод самой недвижимости. Я так понимаю что можно ее переписать чтобы она выводила просто 1 запись, которую указать в айди. Но как его переписать, ума не приложу ведь бэкенд только начал учить, более знаком с фронтендом. Чувствую пятой точкой, что решение где-то на поверхности но уже мозги совсем не варят. Буду благодарен за любую помощь. Кому не тяжело, помогите, пожалуйста, или хотя бы объясните, как найти решение вопроса, чтобы данная запись тянула чисто 1 запись по айди. Пробовал, кстати как обычный пост вывести - не реагирует.

Плагин Insert Page  делает вывод чисто текста без изображений и других виджетов.

```
<?php
// Single property
// Wp Estate Pack
get_header();

global $feature_list_array;
global $propid ;
global $post_attachments;
global $options;

global $where_currency;
global $property_description_text;     
global $property_details_text;
global $property_features_text;
global $property_adr_text;  
global $property_price_text;   
global $property_pictures_text;    
global $propid;
global $gmap_lat;  
global $gmap_long;
global $unit;
global $currency;
global $use_floor_plans;

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$propid                     =   $post->ID;
$options                    =   wpestate_page_details($post->ID);
$gmap_lat                   =   floatval( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'property_latitude', true));
$gmap_long                  =   floatval( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'property_longitude', true));
$unit                       =   esc_html( get_option('wp_estate_measure_sys', '') );
$currency                   =   esc_html( get_option('wp_estate_currency_label_main', '') );
$use_floor_plans            =   intval( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'use_floor_plans', true) );      


if (function_exists('icl_translate') ){
    $where_currency             =   icl_translate('wpestate','wp_estate_where_currency_symbol', esc_html( get_option('wp_estate_where_currency_symbol', '') ) );
    $property_description_text  =   icl_translate('wpestate','wp_estate_property_description_text', esc_html( get_option('wp_estate_property_description_text') ) );
    $property_details_text      =   icl_translate('wpestate','wp_estate_property_details_text', esc_html( get_option('wp_estate_property_details_text') ) );
    $property_features_text     =   icl_translate('wpestate','wp_estate_property_features_text', esc_html( get_option('wp_estate_property_features_text') ) );
    $property_adr_text          =   icl_translate('wpestate','wp_estate_property_adr_text', esc_html( get_option('wp_estate_property_adr_text') ) );  
    $property_price_text        =   icl_translate('wpestate','wp_estate_property_price_text', esc_html( get_option('wp_estate_property_price_text') ) ); 
    $property_pictures_text     =   icl_translate('wpestate','wp_estate_property_pictures_text', esc_html( get_option('wp_estate_property_pictures_text') ) );  
}else{
    $where_currency             =   esc_html( get_option('wp_estate_where_currency_symbol', '') );
    $property_description_text  =   esc_html( get_option('wp_estate_property_description_text') );
    $property_details_text      =   esc_html( get_option('wp_estate_property_details_text') );
    $property_features_text     =   esc_html( get_option('wp_estate_property_features_text') );
    $property_adr_text          =   stripslashes ( esc_html( get_option('wp_estate_property_adr_text') ) );
    $property_price_text        =   esc_html( get_option('wp_estate_property_price_text') );
    $property_pictures_text     =   esc_html( get_option('wp_estate_property_pictures_text') ); 
}


$agent_id                   =   '';
$content                    =   '';
$userID                     =   $current_user->ID;
$user_option                =   'favorites'.$userID;
$curent_fav                 =   get_option($user_option);
$favorite_class             =   'isnotfavorite'; 
$favorite_text              =   esc_html__( 'Add to Favorites','wpestate');
$feature_list               =   esc_html( get_option('wp_estate_feature_list') );
$feature_list_array         =   explode( ',',$feature_list);
$pinteres                   =   array();
$property_city              =   get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'property_city', '', ', ', '') ;
$property_area              =   get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'property_area', '', ', ', '');



$property_category          =   get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'property_category', '', ', ', '') ;
$property_category_terms    =   get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'property_category' );

if(is_array($property_category_terms) ){
    $temp                       =   array_pop($property_category_terms);
    $property_category_terms_icon =   $temp->slug;
    $place_id                   =   $temp->term_id;
    $term_meta                  =   get_option( "taxonomy_$place_id");
    if( isset($term_meta['category_icon_image']) && $term_meta['category_icon_image']!='' ){
        $property_category_terms_icon=$term_meta['category_icon_image'];
    }else{
        $property_category_terms_icon =  get_template_directory_uri().'/img/'.$temp->slug.'-ico.png';
    }
}



$property_action            =   get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'property_action_category', '', ', ', '');   
$property_action_terms      =   get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'property_action_category' );

if(is_array($property_action_terms) ){
    $temp                       =   array_pop($property_action_terms);
    $place_id                   =   $temp->term_id;
    $term_meta                  =   get_option( "taxonomy_$place_id");
    if( isset($term_meta['category_icon_image']) && $term_meta['category_icon_image']!='' ){
        $property_action_terms_icon=$term_meta['category_icon_image'];
    }else{
        $property_action_terms_icon =  get_template_directory_uri().'/img/'.$temp->slug.'-ico.png';
    }
}

$slider_size                =   'small';
$guests                     =   floatval( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'guest_no', true));
$bedrooms                   =   floatval( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'property_bedrooms', true));
$bathrooms                  =   floatval( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'property_bathrooms', true));

$status = stripslashes( esc_html( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'property_status', true) ) );    
if (function_exists('icl_translate') ){
//    $status     =   icl_translate('wpestate','wp_estate_property_status_'.$status, $status ) ;     
    $status = apply_filters( 'wpml_translate_single_string', $property_status, 'wpestate', 'property_status_'.$property_status );
}

if($curent_fav){
    if ( in_array ($post->ID,$curent_fav) ){
        $favorite_class =   'isfavorite';     
        $favorite_text  =   esc_html__( 'Favorite','wpestate').'<i class="fa fa-heart"></i>';
    } 
}

if (has_post_thumbnail()){
    $pinterest = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(),'wpestate_property_full_map');
}


if($options['content_class']=='col-md-12'){
    $slider_size='full';
}


 $listing_page_type    =   get_option('wp_estate_listing_page_type','');

 if($listing_page_type == 2){
    get_template_part('templates/listing_page_2');
 }else{
    get_template_part('templates/listing_page_1');
 }

?>



<?php


    if ( isset($_GET['check_in_prop']) && isset($_GET['check_out_prop'])  && isset($_GET['guest_no_prop'])   ){

        print '<script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[
                jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                    jQuery("#end_date,#start_date").parent().removeClass("calendar_icon");
                    jQuery("#end_date").trigger("change");
                });
                //]]>
        </script>';

    }
//if( is_user_logged_in() ){}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из вопроса не вполне понятно, что у вас где, но примерно так нужно действовать:

```
global $post;
$args = array( 'p' => xxx, 'numberposts' => 1, 'post_type' => 'тип поста недвижимости' );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ){
    setup_postdata($post);
    require_once 'имя файла содержащего код в вопросе';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Разумеется, вместо `xxx` надо вставить ID нужного поста, вместо `тип поста недвижимости` - нужный тип поста, а вместо `имя файла содержащего код в вопросе` - путь и имя файла, в котором содержится код, приведённый в вашем вопросе.

Comment: кажись да я намудрил с вопросом. Грубо говоря пытаюсь сделать вывод http://wprentals.org/properties/west-town-3rd-floor-dorm/ вот такой страницы на главную. Я понимаю что самый простой но карявый способ ето редирект но я так понимаю есть же ж и более  правильный способ

Comment: получилось вот так        
<?php       
global $post;
$args = array( 'p' => 149, 'numberposts' => 1, 'post_type' => 'тип поста недвижимости' );
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ){
    setup_postdata($post);
    require_once 'single-estate_property.php';
}
wp_reset_postdata();       
       
  ?>   но что вставить в тип поста?

Comment: Откройте в админке эти объекты недвижимости, наведите на Свойства, внизу увидите тип поста. В моем примере `uni_post_uslugi`  http://take.ms/C21jh

Comment: ура запахало, как тут вам плюс поставить или добавить к репутации? я так понимаю так по сути можна со многими шаблонами делать вывод или ето только частный случай?

Comment: спасибо огромное

Comment: да вот отметили галочкой ответ, как принятый, и хорошо

Comment: так можно делать вывод из шаблонов почти везде